# UIAutomation's dragInsideWithOptions has no effect on iOS7 simulator

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ios-ui-automation

Since I use Xcode 5 and the new iOS 7 simulator to run UIAutomation tests with Instruments, `dragInsideWithOptions` and `dragFromToForDuration` functions have simply no effect. (The same tests worked fine with iOS 6.1 simulator.) Is this a known bug, or the usability of this functions has changed? Is there anyone who could use this function with iOS 7 simulator on iPad?

Comment: Lock screen doesn't work either, as it also uses the dragging function.

Comment: Is this fixed in XCode 5.1?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work on a device (iOS 7.1.2) either.

Comment: Worked fine on an iOS8 device.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here. In addition to dragInsideWithOptions not working, dragFromToForDuration and flickFromTo aren't working either in Xcode 5 with iOS 7. I have been searching and waiting for a solution as well. Until then, swiping won't be possible.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old but it seems that `dragInsideWithOptions` is still not working.

For a `UIScrollView` these methods can be used:

```
scrollUp
scrollDown
scrollLeft
scrollRight
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAScrollViewClassReference/index.html

Ex:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollRight();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround: If you have a page control associated with your scroll view, use:

```
pageIndicator = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().pageIndicators()[0];
pageIndicator.selectPage(1);
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and your workaround worked well. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1):

same issue here.

More than that, the documentation is missing for new iOS7 for everything related to UI Automation

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html

Compare it with current doc, with full method list and description.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html

Comment: Just came to my mind to test it on a device in it works there, at least on my iPad mini with iOS7 GM it works

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: if you want to swipe scroll views containing a button on a later page, just simply tap this (invisible) button, it "scrolls to visible" automatic. (Or call this invisible element's `scrollToVisible()` function.)