# Automated swipe worked on iOS 6 simulator but it doesn't work on iOS 7

Tags: ios6, migration, ios-simulator, ios7, ios-ui-automation

When I record with instruments, I got the following:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.95, y:0.62}, endOffset:{x:0.00, y:0.62}});
```

But if I play it, nothing happens. On iOS 6 it worked fine.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792965/uiautomations-draginsidewithoptions-has-no-effect-on-ios7-simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it wont work on iOS 7 simulator. But as an alternative you can work on device. These method will work fine on device but not on iOS 7 simulator. And if you want to work on simulator you have to wait for new one.