# UIASlider not sliding

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to slide UIASlider. Below is the script.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();

UIALogger.logMessage( "Value Before: " + window.sliders()[0].value() );
window.sliders()[0].dragToValue( 0.5 );
UIALogger.logMessage( "Slider: " + window.sliders()[0].isValid() );
UIALogger.logMessage( "Value After: " + window.sliders()[0].value() );
```

Script is running without any error but slider not sliding.
Log:

```
Value Before: 0%
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().Sliders()[0].dragToValue("0.5");
Slider: true
Value After: 0%
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Objective-C Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"349-volume-slider@2x"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"349-volume-slider@2x"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"349-volume-slider@2x"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentTrackImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentTrackImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I made a testing project and added this code only. then i find out if i set minimum and maximum track image then slider stop sliding. This can be bug or anything else ?
Using X-Code 5

Comment: Omer, I made a single view app with a slider and run your automation script. Slider is sliding for me, so the script is functional. To investigate further, provide minimum project code and versions of your environment.

Comment: @paiv Thank you for your response. i have added code. Hoe you can see edit

Comment: Omer, still everything works fine for me. What iOS version do you test on? Simulator or on device?

Comment: Do you get errors in Instruments while running the script?

Comment: Testing on iOS 7 iphone 4s.
'Unexpected error in -[UIASlider_0x17ec88f0 dragToValue:], /SourceCache/UIAutomation/UIAutomation-365/Framework/UIAItemElements.m'
Im not sure what is this. Error in script or what... cuz slider isn't just sliding everything else doing great.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Try closing the apps, and moving /SourceCache/UIAutomation away temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is known bug, depending on your iOS testing environment and instrument version it can go from not sliding at all to sliding to an incorrect value. Some folks have filled up a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=UIASlider). Seems to be the same for dragInsideWithOptions and dragFromToForDuration.

You are not [alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792965/uiautomations-draginsidewithoptions-has-no-effect-on-ios7-simulator) with that problem.

Try out [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) to see if it has been solved by apple

Comment: Im not using Simulator. Im testing my app on real device

Comment: Well looks like it's affecting both. Have you tried xcode 6 ?

Comment: X-Code 6 :O nope and i have not heard about x-code 6

Comment: then try it, it is now available for developers

Comment: @gomino it still doesn't work on latest Xcode 6.4 :( Do you know of another way to move the slider?